# Angular 5 Error:Trying to import a source file from a node_modules /node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead-container.component.ngfactory.ts

Tags: build, compiler-errors, angular5, ngx-bootstrap, aot

Do you have anybody some advice, idea, how can I fix the following error?

This occurred when I ran production build.
It's more interesting when I ran the production build with -aot=false it was successes.

ERROR in : Error: Trying to import a source file from a node_modules package: import C:...search-scrollbar.directive.ts from C:
.../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead-container.component.ngfactory.ts
    at TsCompilerAotCompilerTypeCheckHostAdapter.fileNameToModuleName (C:...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\compiler_host.js:187:19)
    at AotCompiler._fileNameToModuleName (C:...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:31099:24)
    at Object.importExpr$$1 [as importExpr] (C:...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:31067:55)
    at singleProviderDef (C:...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:20028:28)
    at providerDef (C:...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:19962:9)
    at ViewBuilder._visitProviderOrDirective (C:...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:28177:18)
    at ViewBuilder._visitDirective (C:...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:28025:23)
    at C:...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:27926:32
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ViewBuilder._visitElementOrTemplate (C:...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:27916:23)
    at ViewBuilder.visitElement (C:...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:27820:23)
    at ElementAst.visit (C:...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:925:24)
    at visit (C:...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1366:37)
    at C:...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1368:42
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at templateVisitAll (C:...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1367:10)

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You're importing source `*.ts` files instead of compiled `*.js` files. Make sure you really need that. If yes – try to enable `preserveSymlinks: true` option in `angular.json` and/or `tsconfig.json` file(s). It solved this error in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue recently and got fixed after updating the tsconfig.json file and the tsconfig.app.json file

here are the updated configurations.

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"],
    "module": "esnext"
  },
  "exclude": [
   "test.ts",
   "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json file

```
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "module": "es2015",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "importHelpers": true,
  "target": "es6",
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "lib": [
    "es2018",
    "dom"
  ],
```